# Inserindo Componente Vue no DOM via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Estou usando Vue em uma aplicação onde tenho uma lista de itens e um botão para adicionar mais itens.
Ao clicar em adicionar eu carrego um html externo com um componente:

```
    <div class="gutters-8 col-lg-6">
     <div class="form-group combined-inputs">
      <span class="upload-image">
        <label>
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE439;</i>
        <input type="file">
        </label>
      </span>

      <input-animate label="Descrição do produto" type="text"></input-animate>     
    </div>
  </div>
```

A página abre porém não renderiza o componente.

Ao clicar no botão para adicionar o componente, é chamado o método addProduct:

```
methods: {
    addProduct: function() {
      $.get('/do/Suppliers.mvc/ProdutoCatalogo')
      .then(function(page){          
          $('.products-list').prepend(page)
      }, function(){
        console.log('Erro ao carregar a página')
      })
    }
}
```

Teria como dar tipo um refresh somente no componente?

Comment: Como está não precisa de "refresh", deveria funcionar. Como está as marcações do html que vai inserir? Se estiver tentando colocar `<html>` dentro de `<html>` não vai funcionar

Comment: Pode ser isso, vou confirmar

Comment: Não tem tag <html> na página externa que estou chamando

Comment: Existe o elemento com a class `.products-list`?

Comment: Existe sim. Esta página externa ela tem outros elementos html além do componente. Estes outros aprecem normalmente, somente a tag do componente que parece ficar invisivel, pois no html ela aparece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido!!
Criei um array que seria como que o v-model dessa lista que eu vou adicionando na tela.

Então cerquei meu codigo html com v-for iterando essa lista:
**v-for="item in itemList"**

```
<div class="gutters-8 col-lg-6" v-for="item in itemList">
     <div class="form-group combined-inputs">
      <span class="upload-image">
        <label>
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE439;</i>
        <input type="file">
        </label>
      </span>

      <input-animate label="Descrição do produto" type="text"></input-animate>     
    </div>
  </div>
```

Inclui esse itemList no meu data().

E o addProduct ficou assim:

```
methods: {
    addProduct: function() {
      this.itemList.push({itemID:''})
    }
}
```