# Inserir component depois da renderização Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js, vue.js-2

Oi, estou aprendendo como que se usa Vue.js e até o momento estou sabendo como que cria components.

Porem estou como uma dificuldade, estou querendo renderizar um componente depois de carregar a pagina. Eu no meu projeto vou fazer call ajaxs e com o json que receber, inserir os componentes, mas antes, para testar a renderização deles estou usando esse código Jquery basico:

```
$('#test123').html('<inventory message="Click on the Item to activate it."></inventory>');
```

Porem esse componente não é renderizado e não acontece nada com ele, eu vi algumas coisas na internet, porem as soluções que eu achei renderizava um componente só, mas eu preciso renderizar varios, porque o json que eu vou receber, o javascript vai fazer foreach e colocar na div.

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Cara não sei por onde está aprendendo **Vue**, mas não está indo em um caminho bacana não! Só de utilizar jQuery junto com Vue, já demonstra isto. Não entendi muito bem o que quer fazer, mas, Vue.js tem em uma das suas premissas principais a **NÃO** manipulação direta do DOM, te aconselho a ir aprendendo na documentação oficial no site: https://br.vuejs.org/

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254378/inserindo-componente-vue-no-dom-via-jquery

Comment: Olá @LeAndrade, estou usando Jquery só como teste, pois estou começando a aprender a usar Vue, e estou sabendo usar no momento componentes, esse Jquery era só para fazer um teste. Meu objetivo é que, no meu projeto vai ter tipo um joguinho, onde você tem seu inventario e seus itens, eu quero fazer com que quando o usuario clique para usar/ativar o item, a api vai retornar um json do inventario atualizado (sem o item, pois ele acabo de usar), só que os itens são componentes, fiz o teste com jquery e vi que o Vue não renderizava eles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O VueJS possui um ciclo de vida próprio. https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html na própria documentação ele explica os métodos que controlam esse ciclo de vida. Ao invés de usar  o Jquery, o VueJS também tem o reatividade para código HTML, para isso, você pode usar "v-html" ao invés do "v-model" ou "v-bind".

Comment: Desculpa cara, mas não entendi muito bem como eu posso resolver o meu problema com o v-html :/ poderia me explicar melhor, por favor?

Comment: Diferente do v-model e v-bind, esses controlam o valor de input ou select, por exemplo. O V-HTML  vai permitir escrever código HTML e o VueJS escreverá esse html para ser executado.

Comment: Você pode criar um atributo na sua instância do Vue e adiconar da seguinte forma: "<div id="teste123" v-html="html"></div>". Quando o call do ajax ser executado, você pode fazer o foreach e adcionar a variável html.